# Aggregation with a min in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to aggregate datas dates on the minimum value. I tried to use a groupby() but it gives an error.

```
   history= history.selectExpr('aaa'\
        , 'bbb'\
        , 'ccc'\
        , 'date')

        history=history.groupBy()('aaa','bbb','ccc',min('date'))
```

I tried first

```
       history= history.selectExpr('aaa'\
            , 'bbb'\
            , 'ccc'\
            , min('date'))
```

but it didn't work neither

Thank you :)

Comment: when you say you want to groupby min of date do you mean min on entire dataset or min within aaa, bbb, ccc grouping? What do you want to do with the grouping - what kind of result dfo you want to see out of the final transformation?

Comment: Hello Tetlanesh, thanks for your answer.

I would like to have dataset keeping only rows with the minimum date:

If i have:

AAA BBB CCC 01/12
AAA BBB CCC 01/01

I would have:

AAA BBB CCC 01/01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do that :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
history.groupBy("AAA","BBB","CCC").agg(F.min("date"))
```

Comment: thank you Steven:

I have the following issue:

  "    from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date, date_sub, functions as F
  ImportError: cannot import name functions     "

Comment: that's normal, you didnt write what i wrote.